# Define enum in javascript for some states

Tags: javascript, enums

I need to create enum to display mode for example withData, withoutData ,mockData, etc in addition of other part of the screen info I need to create enum to for radio button withPreview,withoutPreview,fullScreen...

Should I create one enum to fits it all or should I define two(like below) for all states ?
2. how to use it in the code?

```
var dataStates = {
    withData: 0,
    withOutdata: 1,
    mockData: 2
};


var displayStates = {
    withPreview: 0,
    withouPreview: 1,
    fullScreen: 2
};
```

Comment: is there any relation between withPreview, withoutPreview and fullScreen and the dataStates? If yes you better merge and express that relation and if not leave them separate

Comment: @XGreen- Currently not....and how should I call it like dataStates.withData ?

Comment: Yes you would call it dataStates.withData which I am guessing you would check against something that comes from the server to check if response.stateState == dataStates.withData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define something like this:

```
var dataStates = {
    withData: 0,
    withOutdata: 1,
    mockData: 2
};

var displayStates = {
    withPreview: 0,
    withouPreview: 1,
    fullScreen: 2
};

var state = {
    data: dataStates.withData,
    display: displayStates.withPreview
}
```

You can then call `state.data` or `state.display` and it will return the number value. If you need to make comparisons, you could use this `state.data === dataStates.withData`, or another valid enum/object value.

For multiple states, you could do the following:

```
var states = {
    name1: {
       data: dataStates.withData,
       display: displayStates.withPreview
    },
    name2: {
       etc
    }
};
```

And then call `states.name1` or something else you have defined.